# How do I sort the result of sheet.getMergedRegions() in apache-poi

Tags: java, sorting, apache-poi

I used getMergedRegions() function of apache poi which returns a list of cellRangeAddresses. However, the result seems to bedisorganized.

```
        List<CellRangeAddress> cellRangeAddressList = sheet.getMergedRegions();
```

This gave the following result:

> [org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [C2:C5], org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [B2:B5], org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [A2:A5],
>   [org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [C6:C9], org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [B6:B9], org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [A6:A9], ]org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [C10:C13], org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [B10:B13], org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [A10:A13]]

The result is in an order that does not help my code. I want the order to be

> [org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [A2:A5], org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [B2:B5], org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [C2:C5],
>   [org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [A6:A9], org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [B6:B9], org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [C6:C9], ]org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [A10:A13], org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [B10:B13], org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [C10:C13]]

Is there any way I can get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sheet.getMergedRegions` gets the merged regions in the order they were added. But of course there is [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) which is able sorting a given `List` using given `Comparator`.

So main task is defining that `Comparator`.

Working draft:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

class ExcelMergedRegions {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook  = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,4,2,2)); //C2:C5
  sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,4,1,1)); //B2:B5
  sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,4,0,0)); //A2:A5
  sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(5,8,2,2)); //C6:C9
  sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(5,8,1,1)); //B6:B9
  sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(5,8,0,0)); //A6:A9
  sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(9,12,2,2)); //C10:C13
  sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(9,12,0,0)); //A10:A13

  sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,5,3,4)); //D2:E6
  sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(2,2,5,7)); //F3:H3

  List<CellRangeAddress> cellRangeAddressList = sheet.getMergedRegions();
  System.out.println(cellRangeAddressList);

  System.out.println("Sorted list:");

  Collections.sort(cellRangeAddressList, new CellRangeAddressComperator());
  System.out.println(cellRangeAddressList);

 }

 static class CellRangeAddressComperator implements java.util.Comparator<CellRangeAddress> {
  public int compare(CellRangeAddress o1, CellRangeAddress o2) {
   int r = 0;
   // first compare first rows
   r = o1.getFirstRow() - o2.getFirstRow();
   if (r != 0 ) return r;
   // if first rows are equal, compare first columns
   r = o1.getFirstColumn() - o2.getFirstColumn();
   if (r != 0 ) return r;
   // if first rows and first columns are equal, compare last rows
   r = o1.getLastRow() - o2.getLastRow();
   if (r != 0 ) return r;
   // if even last rows are equal, compare last columns
   r = o1.getLastColumn() - o2.getLastColumn();
   if (r != 0 ) return r;
   // if all is equal, return 0
   return r;
  }
 }
}
```

I hope my `Comparator` definition makes sense for all possible cases. But, if not, you should be able refining it. The approach using a `Comparator` definitely is the correct  one.